# How to move the debug console to another window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This window:
[image]

I tried to follow this comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19793#issuecomment-344985923

But I did not understand well how does it work.

What I did was open two instance of vscode with the same script file, and set both to the same workspace.

Then i run the script in first instance but the code print to the console did not shown in the second instance, or this is not how it work?

Comment: if you start 2 web browsers and you use `console.log` in one of them, do you expect to see the result in the other browser? VSC runs on Google Chrome (Electron)

Comment: @rioV8 What the guy in that comment suggests so?

Comment: The comment just says you can open VSC two times and move one of the windows to a second monitor and debug the application there, but all your debug output will be shown in the window where the debugger runs. Maybe you can look at the Debugger Protocol and write a program that connects to the debugger and only shows the debug output.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "externalConsole": true, in the launch.json and move the terminal to another monitor

Comment: This would create an external terminal instead of the requested debugging console.

Answer (score -1):

Open your workspace in a second window where you can watch your run and debug panel. In the first window you can do your coding.

1. Open your workspace
2. Press CTRL + SHIFT + P and then search for Duplicate As Workspace in New Window
3. A second windows open with your current workspace
4. in one of them you can watch your debugging in the other do your coding